# WPF application crash when using Background worker in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, backgroundworker

am using the WPF with MVVM

in background worker am calling the method the sendEmail

when am trying to send 10 or 15 emails the application gets crash

if i use the background worker to send 1 or 2 email is working.

whats is issue here, any problem with the thread

```
crash in  vshost.exe has stopped working
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
```

Comment: "my app crashes" is not helpful at all. At least provide the error message and the stacktrace. Even better: add the code that causes the crash to happen.

Comment: vshost.exe 
and 
says Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll

Comment: I would suggest posting some code and showing where in the code the exception is occurring.  Based on your question it sounds like you haven't even tried to debug it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Random guess : the server is refusing your client's connection because it has already openned too many connections.